# creating delegate new instance of MouseEventHandler

Tags: c#, delegates, mouseevent, anonymous-function

When creating buttons dynamically, i wished to have a new MouseEventHandler. I did this like so,

```
this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(generalMethods.generatePopup());
```

However, as i needed to pass parameters to the event, i made generatePopup to accept an integer which would denote button number (so i could use further). In the past i would have just used an anonymous delegate to pass additional parameters across, but this doesn't seem to work as i want to create a NEW instance, as such;

```
this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { new MouseEventHandler( generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, e, i); };
```

it seems that the error is on new MouseEventHandler. if i take this out, it works fine and i can pass additional data, but because it is not a new instance it doesn't give each button its own event, like so;

```
this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(generalMethods.generatePopup());
```

does anyone know how to work around this? for example to use the anon delegate approach still, but still creating a new instance of the event?

EDIT: hmm, i tried this (parameters pass fine i believe) but it seems as though instead of creating a new mouseeventhandler for each button, it's using the same one for all of the buttons, as i've set a label to test it's getting the right button number, but all of the labels on the popup's are returning the last button number instead of their correct one. any ideas?

EDIT 2: here's my code block for generating buttons:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 2; i++)
        {

            Button btnAdd = new Button();
            btnAdd.Text = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceDescription"].ToString();
            btnAdd.Location = new Point(x, y);
            btnAdd.Tag = i;
            btnAdd.Name = "btn" + i.ToString();
            btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Green;

            this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);

            this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    int index = i;
    generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, e, index);
};
```

and here's my generatePopup method, which is the mouseEventHandler:

```
public void generatePopup(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, int buttonNumber)
    {
      //  DBConnector mDBConnector = new DBConnector();
      //  DataTable dataTable = mDBConnector.Select("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE deviceID = " + buttonNumber);


        DeviceBreakdownPopup popupDevice = new DeviceBreakdownPopup();
        popupDevice.lblDeviceNo.Text = buttonNumber.ToString();

        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupDevice);
        popup.Show(Cursor.Position);

    }
```

here's an image of what's happening to, just for clarity:

[image: example of error]

Here we see both popup usercontrols given the label "2", whereas i need each to have their correct value, "1" and "2".

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(
    (sender, evt) => {
        generalMethods.generatePopup()
    }
);
```

The `new MouseEventHandler(...)` part is optional - the compiler figures out the parameter types from the left side of the `+=` assignment.

**EDIT** The problem with your code is that *it accesses modified closure*. You should make a temp variable from `i`, and use it inside your lambda to fix the problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 2; i++)
    {

        Button btnAdd = new Button();
        btnAdd.Text = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceDescription"].ToString();
        btnAdd.Location = new Point(x, y);
        btnAdd.Tag = i;
        btnAdd.Name = "btn" + i.ToString();
        btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Green;

        this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
        var temp = i;
        this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
            int index = temp;
            generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, e, index);
        };
}
```

Comment: hmm, i tried this (parameters pass fine i believe) but it seems as though instead of creating a new mouseeventhandler for each button, it's using the same one for all of the buttons, as i've set a label to test it's getting the right button number, but all of the labels on the popup's are returning the last button number instead of their correct one. any ideas? i'll pop this in my edit so everyone can see  easier.

Comment: I guess I'm having a misunderstanding of what you're trying to do: what's in the `generalMethods.generatePopup()` method? Could you please also post the loop or the sequence of assignments where you add the handler to different buttons?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter See the edit - you cannot use `i` in the delegate, because it is modified in the loop. Make a copy in a temp variable, and use it instead.

Comment: like a boss : D this works perfectly. i'll keep in mind what you said about creating the temp integer because i was modified in the loop, i wonder how many other people have got stuck coming across something like this.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter It is considered a very common problem indeed. I would be regularly getting into this trap if it were not for ReSharper that alerts me to the issue.

Comment: well thank you very much, seems like these little traps are things you don't really know what's going wrong unless you already know the answer..and..well...that's just silly!

Answer (score 1):

What type does `generatePopup` return? If it returns a `MouseEventHandler` already, then you should be fine (as long as a new handler is generated for each instance). Something along the lines of:

```
btnAdd.MouseClick += generalMethods.generatePopup();

/* in generalMethods */
private static int ButtonIndex = 0;
public MouseEventHandler generatePopup()
{
   int tempIndex = ButtonIndex++;
   return new MouseEventHandler((sender, ea) => generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, ea, tempIndex));
}
```

The reason you do it this way is because the `generatePopup` method will create a new `MouseEventHandler` for each button. Each handler that gets generated will create a closure for the lambda you created, adding the `tempIndex` variable that we set as a local field. So when the handler is created, creates new closure over the lambda (including the tempIndex) and will call the generatePopup method for each individual button (it's local version of tempIndex). Closure over variables happens OUTSIDE the Lambda, so you should set a local variable *before* you specify the Lambda and it will be properly captured.

Give it a try and let us know.

Edit: so I see you're generating the buttons in a loop. Will there ever be a situation in which they are dynamically generated (IE: not within that loop, sometime AFTER the initial create)?  If so, you've already got all the information on the button itself:

```
(sender, ea) => generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, ea, (int)((Control)sender).Tag)
```

Since you've already attached the index to the Tag, you don't ever need to worry about having a different version of the index for different buttons. In your current version, you're trying to get a reference of the loop variable itself (which gets reused), so by the time you're done with the loop all instances of the MouseEventHandler reference the loop variable **in its final state**. Loop variables and Lambdas don't mix unless you create a temporary variable to store the intermediate value.

Comment: just made an edit as you posted this. contains my methods, does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is to create an inherited control and add your own event and a property. Your event will populate the property when instantiated and call the mouseclick when triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard event pattern. You can retrieve the source of the event and cast it to the desired type.

```
this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MyControl_MouseClick);

//...

void MyControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;

    if (button.Name == "Add") // here is how to retrieve the button name
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that (albeit you wouldn't have known without program background) is that i'm doing a polling service, for example i have 25 dynamically created buttons. using this method i'd have to do 25 if's for each name, right? if i send the buttonnumber as a parameter i don't have to.

Comment: What about putting data you need in an struct (struc or class) stored in the object Tag property ? Including the buttonnumber.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can not do like this.**

Delegate syntax is followed by the method that attached that particular event. you can create custom control and and custom event for that control.

Here how we create events as:

```
  // Define a delegate named LogHandler, which will encapsulate
    // any method that takes a string as the parameter and returns no value
       public delegate void LogHandler(string message);

    // Define an Event based on the above Delegate
       public event LogHandler Log;
```

Ref [this](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html) and [Events and Delegates simplified](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4773/Events-and-Delegates-simplified).

For creating custom controls follow this - [Creating a Custom Control in Winforms - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2004/12/06/275505.aspx) and [Developing Custom Windows Forms Controls with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx) as:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : TextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += 
  (sender, e) => generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, e, i);
```

This will create a unique anonymous method, with unique arguments, to be called by each button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare the index in inner scope as it would otherwise still reference your loop parameter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++)
{
    this.Controls[name].MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        int index = i;
        generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, e, index);
    }
}
```

You do not need a designated handler for each button (one for all will work fine) but you will have to grant each button its own index object.